# ASP.NET Razor Views considered as non-user code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, visual-studio-2015

I would like to know the reason why the ASP.NET Razor Views (CSHTML files) are considered by Visual Studio as non-user code. I found that **when my MVC is executed by the IIS within an application pool *NOT* allowing 32 bit applications then the views are loaded as non-user code**. (I check it using Visual Studio modules window).

**When the symbols are not loaded and I cannot debug in any view since breakpoints are not hit**. If you ask about the PDB files: they are created along with the DLL of each view. Need to say that if I try to *manullay* load them with via Moduel window it yelds an error becuase apparently the DLL and PDB do not match (?). The breakpoints in other parts of the code work correctly.

**If I enable the 32 bit applications in the pool configuration then the DLL files of the Razor View are loaded as user code and breakpoint work again**.

This issue does not affect to code related with files (CS extension), such as controllers, that are compiled as user code and their symbols loaded without a problem.

I thought it was some kind of misconfiguration of the project related to debug, release configurations. I also deleted bin, obj folders, temporary files… I did all the things the Internet says without luck. The issue was not there, it's in the IIS pool configuration. (I have a dedicated pool for my application).

The mystery expands when my co-worker running the same code and in an almost identic machine can compile the view as user code regardless of the configuration of the pool in the IIS.

There must be some hidden configuration I do not know that makes VS behave like this. I would appreciate if someone can explain how this works. I have a solution turning the pool to enable 32 bit application but I really want to know the implications and origin of the issue.

Thank you very much in advance!